# "And so is everyone else." What is this kind of sentence called in English?

Tags: grammar

"And so is everyone else." What is this kind of sentence called in English? For example:

> Man 1: “You are human.”
>   Man 2: “and so is everyone else.”

Is there any specific name for the kind of sentence Man 2 is saying?

Comment: A [_fragment_](http://www.wordnik.com/words/sentence%20fragment), maybe? In any case, if you want this question taken seriously, then you should probably do some serious elaboration.

Comment: I meant like we have question tag. Is there any specific name in the english language for these sentences also?

Comment: (1) Do not elaborate in comments, please. **Edit your question.** (2) What kind of sentences are you talking about? Ones that begin with a conjunction? Ones that have no subject? Ones that have 80% of the words beginning with a vowel? Ones that express general agreement?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't see what you mean either unless you write out an entire
sentence for us to classify. However, it would be a generalisation
e.g. 'You are human and so is everyone else'.

Comment: Man 1:'You are human' Man 2: and so is everyone else. Is there any specific name for the kind of sentence Man 2 is saying?

Comment: @Lazio Well, with this bit of context it could be a [*rejoinder*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rejoinder) but you must **edit your question** to provide enough information to allow people to give a proper answer. A rejoinder is a type of reply, not a generic name for a particular sentence structure. **What is it that you are asking?**

Answer (score 1):

With the context, where the sentence is a short (and maybe sharp) response to someone else, it could be called a *rejoinder*.

[ODO on rejoinder:](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rejoinder)

> *noun*
>       a reply, especially a sharp or witty one:
>           *she would have made some cutting rejoinder but none came to mind*

Comment: @Lazio However, you are still asking about the type of sentence, not the type of reply, so this may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Andrew. It can be called a rejoinder.